# arcpy path of ArcGIS mapservice layer throws error

Tags: arcpy, map-service

I have a few basemaps published to ArcGIS Server. I have a script that I am running which removes these basemap map services. What I need to do is find the source REST endpoints of these mapservices to further narrow down my script. I have just added as per @Vince suggestion the isServiceLayer as an if statement and tried printing out the serviceProperties but the script throws an error on certain layers

sample **UPDATED** code...

```
f = path 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'{}'.format(f))
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
    for x in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,data_frame=df):
        if x.isGroupLayer:
            name = str(x)
            if name.startswith("Basemaps"):
                if x.isServiceLayer:
                    print x.serviceProperties
                    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,x)
```

**ERROR**

```
_Basemaps_hcgis
_Basemaps_hcgis\ Region
{u'UserName': u'arcgis', u'Supportsrsa': u'-1', u'ServiceType': u'MapServer', u'Connectionfile': u'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.3\\ArcCatalog\\arcgis on SERVER (admin).ags', u'Connectionmode': u'1', u'URL': u'http://SERVER', u'Servertype': u'1', u'Restversion': u'10.3', u'Rsaurl': u'http://SERVER', u'Server': u'', u'Adminurl': u'http://SERVER', u'Resturl': u'http://SERVER', u'Soapurl': u'http://SERVER', u'Handshakefinished': u'-1', u'Anonymous': u'0', u'Usedefaultstagingfolder': u'-1', u'Admintokenurl': u'http://SERVER', u'Stagingfolder': u'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arc434C\\Staging'}
_Basemaps_hcgis\ Region\>570000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\blah.py", line 11, in <module>
    print x.serviceProperties
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 78, in _get
    (attr_name, self.__class__.__name__))
NameError: The attribute 'serviceProperties' is not supported on this instance of Layer.
```

**UPDATE** from @Alex suggestions:

my mapserver basemaps are in a group layer named **Basemaps** and I only want to remove those basemaps... the problem is I am running this script through network drives so some of the old MXDS(before my time) have two group layers called **Basemaps** group layer, 1 from the old server and 1 from the new one. I DO NOT want to remove the new **Basemaps ** group layer and the only way to accomplish this is to open up each mapservice and check which server it is from... here is a picture of how it is set up

[image]

Comment: Your looping is suspect -- `ListLayers` does not restrict by data frame (your code would not work with multiple data frames).  The [Layer documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) lists the properties, including `.isServiceLayer` and `.serviceProperties`

Comment: @Vince so remove for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd): and I will be able to loop through all the dateframes? because that is what I am trying to do

Comment: i call arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df,x) don't I need to reference the dataframe for that?...

Comment: Look at your logic. You'd act on all layers as being in any data frame. You need to specify `ListLayers(...,data_frame=df)` to use your current looping structure

Comment: gotcha okay I see what you mean I fixed it

Comment: @ziggy, did I understand it right that you want to 1. find a layer in the map document TOC that is of type ArcGIS Server map service. 2. Remove it from the TOC. ?

Comment: as per comment suggestions I have updated the code and question to reflect my current problem. @AlexTereshenkov yes to both

Comment: @ziggy, I hope I got you right, posted the answer.

Comment: @ziggy, so you have one group layer called `Basemaps`. Under this group layer, you can have both ArcGIS Server map services layers as well as regular map layers that come from other data sources such as shapefiles and geodatabases. You want to remove the layer if it is of the ArcGIS Server map service type. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ArcGIS map services are added to the map document as group layers. This means you need to check whether a layer is both a group layer AND a service layer.

This code will remove all layers that are ArcGIS Server services and the server machine they come from has `oldservername` in the URL. There are other properties which you can use instead of the `Resturl`, consult the [docs](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm).

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, data_frame=df):    
        if lyr.isGroupLayer and lyr.isServiceLayer:
            if 'oldservername' in lyr.serviceProperties['Resturl']:
                arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
```

This code will find all ArcGIS Server based map services and remove them from the map document. I use the `current` map document for simplicity.

Comment: updated my question!

Comment: @ziggy, this code will remove all the ArcGIS Server map services regardless of where they are in the TOC (under `Basemaps` or not). Is this working for you?

Comment: yes but I was able to do that before I asked this question... I really need to open up each service layer and check to see which server it is on, its on the old one then remove it. sorry if I have unclear I did not set up any of these mapservices at my work so im learning on the fly

Comment: should I ask a new question?

Comment: np, updated the answer

Comment: beauty, thanks! had to add try except block and some other code but this is what I wanted